# App force closes when opening messaging app

Tags: android, start-activity

```
    final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    //get a list of installed apps.
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        String packagename = ((String) packageInfo.loadLabel(pm)).replaceAll(" ", "").toLowerCase();
        if(packagename.contains(appname)){
            say("Opening"+appname);
            Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName);
            Log.v(TAG, ""+launchIntent);
            context.startActivity(launchIntent);
        }
```

Using this code, my app force closes when opening messaging, and only messaging. It does open the messaging app, but force closes and throws a null pointer exception. Any ideas?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Post exception logcat

Answer (score 0):

I suspect

```
String packagename = ((String) packageInfo.loadLabel(pm))...
```

is not a reasonable way to get the package name.

Why not

`public String  packageName`    *Name of the package that this item is in*?